# How can I alert a message box when no selection was made in the Excel drop-down?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In my Excel sheet I have a column that was filled up with a list of values to be selected.

When the user didn't select an item from the list and tried to save, I would like to show a message box stating that you have to select an item – or is there any option to make the `first item` get selected from the list?

[image]

Sheet with `AddressType` this i am calling in my next sheet in which ever `column` i required by using `Data validations` available so that it comes as follows

[image]

By default i would like to select `Office` or if the user didn't select any i would like to display an error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-remove-a-drop-down-list-HP005202215.aspx) -- click the `+How` links to expand the info on the page.

To post an error message, uncheck `Ignore blank` and go to `Error Alert` to change the error message.

[image]

<sup>This is the Excel 2007 version of the dialog, but I don't think it has undergone any radical changes</sup>

To make a default value for your dropdown cell, just [type that into the cell](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/excel-2003-default-value-validation-drop-down-list-t1049613.html) and save the sheet that way.  It seems there is no way to do this through the validation system itself.